# Factoring and solving a quadratic polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics, factors

So i code stuff for my **fx-cg50 calculator's micropython** as I'm an a level student and a python beginner, and i need help pointing out the bugs and some programming tips to further improve my code, and i can't use sympy or numpy since they cant fit in my calculator's measly 16 MB so i have to make everything from scratch: **disclaimer**, my code can't factor expressions by completing the square, so if you guys have any idea about how i could get started tell me, i was planning on using my program to begin with to get a factored quadratic expression anyways, and move on from there.

and can anyone tell me what level my code is at, relatively for reference sake.

```
from math import sqrt, pi, isclose, gcd

print("ax+by+c=0")


def gcd_2(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a


def fraction(a):
    factor = 0
    while True:
        factor += 1
        a_rounded = int(round(a*factor))
        if isclose(a*factor, a_rounded, abs_tol=0.01):
            text = ("{}/{}".format(a_rounded, factor))
            return text


def simplify_fraction(numer, denom):
    if denom == 0:
        return "Division by 0 - result undefined"

    # Remove greatest common divisor:
    common_divisor = gcd_2(numer, denom)
    (reduced_num, reduced_den) = (numer / common_divisor, denom / common_divisor)
    # Note that reduced_den > 0 as documented in the gcd function.

    if common_divisor == 1:
        return (numer, denom)
    else:
        # Bunch of nonsense to make sure denominator is negative if possible
        if (reduced_den > denom):
            if (reduced_den * reduced_num < 0):
                return (-reduced_num, -reduced_den)
            else:
                return (reduced_num, reduced_den)
        else:
            return (reduced_num, reduced_den)


def quadratic_function(a, b, c):
    a_original, b_original, c_original = a, b, c
    if b ** 2 - 4 * a * c >= 0:
        negative_factor = False
        if a < 0:
            negative_factor = True
        #  checks if gcf can be applied to simplify the quadratic expression
        b_divisible_by_a = (b % a == 0)
        c_divisible_by_a = (c % a == 0)
        check_divisible = (b_divisible_by_a and c_divisible_by_a)
        a_is_one = (a == (a/a))
        if negative_factor:
            gcf = -int(gcd(int(-a), gcd(int(-b), int(-c))))
            b, c, a = -b, -c, -a
        if a_is_one or (check_divisible is False):
            gcf = ""
        elif check_divisible and (a_is_one is False):
            if negative_factor is False:
                gcf = int(gcd(int(-a), gcd(int(-b), int(-c))))
            b, c, a = b/a, c/a, a/a
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
        # Added a "-" to these next 2 values because they would be moved to the other side of the equation
        mult1 = -x1 * a
        mult2 = -x2 * a
        (num1, den1) = simplify_fraction(a, mult1)
        (num2, den2) = simplify_fraction(a, mult2)
        if (num1 > a) or (num2 > a):
            # simplify fraction will make too large of num and denom to try to make a sqrt work
            print("No factorization")
            c =(b/2)**2

        else:
            # Getting ready to make the print look nice
            if (den1 > 0):
                sign1 = "+"
            else:
                sign1 = ""
            if (den2 > 0):
                sign2 = "+"
            else:
                sign2 = ""
            print("The Factored Form is:\n{}({}x{}{})({}x{}{})".format(gcf, int(num1), sign1, int(den1), int(num2), sign2,int(den2)))
    else:
        # if the part under the sqrt is negative, you have a solution with i
        print("Solutions are imaginary")
    return


while True:
    try:
        stop_flag = 0
        stop_or_continue = ""
        a = float(eval(input("insert a: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))
        b = float(eval(input("insert b: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))
        c = float(eval(input("insert c: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))

        quadratic_function(a, b, c)

        discriminant = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c


        if discriminant == 0:
            x_one = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)   # x_one
            if eval(fraction(x_one)) % 1 == 0:
                print("x1 is : ", x_one)
            else:
                print("x1 is : ", fraction(x_one))
        if discriminant > 0:
            x_one = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)  # x_one
            if eval(fraction(x_one)) % 1 == 0:
                print("x1 is : ", x_one)
            else:
                print("x1 is : ", fraction(x_one))
            x_two = (-b - sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)  # x_two
            if eval(fraction(x_two)) % 1 == 0:
                print("x2 is : ", x_two)
            else:
                print("x2 is : ", fraction(x_two))
        if discriminant < 0:
            pass

        while stop_or_continue != "a" or "b":
            stop_or_continue = input("Stop?: ")
            if stop_or_continue == "a":
                stop_flag = 1
                break
            if stop_or_continue == "b":
                stop_flag = 0
                break
        if stop_flag == 1:
            break

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: You say quadratic, but the expression you print `ax + by + c = 0` is linear.

Comment: @AJNeufeld ahh sorry thats a small mistake but the code is for quadratic really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Repetition

You write:

```
discriminant = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
```

followed by:

```
    if discriminant == 0:
        x_one = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)   # x_one
        ...
    if discriminant > 0:
        x_one = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)  # x_one
        ...
        x_two = (-b - sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)  # x_two
        ...
```

Any reason why you don't use `sort(discriminant)`?

This continues in `quadratic_function`, with:

```
if b ** 2 - 4 * a * c >= 0:
    ...
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
```

## Repetition (reprise)

```
    a = float(eval(input("insert a: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))
    b = float(eval(input("insert b: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))
    c = float(eval(input("insert c: ").replace("pi", str(pi))))
```

Looks like you could use a common function here:

```
def query_float(prompt):
    return float(eval(input(prompt).replace("pi", str(pi))))

    a = query_float("insert a: ")
    b = query_float("insert b: ")
    c = query_float("insert c: ")
```

## Repetition (reprise, reprised)

```
        if eval(fraction(x_one)) % 1 == 0:
            print("x1 is : ", x_one)
        else:
            print("x1 is : ", fraction(x_one))
```

This block of code appears 3 times (once with `x_two`).  In the process of executing the block, it calls `fraction(x_one)`, which is a time-consuming search function, looping through up to 100 divisors, trying to find one that works.  Then, the resulting fraction expression is evaluated, and if it is not an integer, `fraction(x_one)` is again called, despite having been already computed moments earlier!

If `fraction()` simply returned the "value", instead of "value/1", when `factor == 1`, then the caller would simply:

```
        print("x1 is : ", fraction(x_one))
```

## Stop or Continue

It is unclear why the user would answer `"a"` or `"b"` to the question `input("Stop?: ")`.

Comment: ahh its because ill be inputting everything from a calculator and a and b are right beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

This type of program, can really use OOP, it will help maintain it much better, by making classes for designated functions, and the pi replacer function can be a part of it.

Comment: I would be helpful if you could show some examples of how this might be transformed to OOP.